# SSRS WinForm Report Viewer Actions

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

I am looking at the report viewer WinForms control in SSRS 2005 and want to know if you can have actions do something other than call a URL or show another report.  My boss likes the report viewer control but wants to know if you can set it up so that if you click on a cell it could open up another form.

I think the "Action" property is the right tool for this, but I don't see any options to run code... all I see is "Go TO Bookmark","Jump to Report", and "Go to URL".  Is there an event that the control exposes that I could use to determine which cell was clicked or some other way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, there's a [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.hyperlink.aspx) event on the ReportViewer control that is fired whenever the user clicks on a link within a report. You might be able to handle that event, set Cancel to true, and take your own action.

Just to clarify - this would mean using the "Go to URL" action but specifying a URL that you can parse yourself. For example, "http://example.com?action=ShowHelloWorld". Then you could parse the [e.Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.hyperlinkeventargs.hyperlink.aspx) property and decide what action to take.